# Show that if a bipartite graph $G = (V, E)$ with bipartition $V = A \cup B$ is $k$-regular, then $|A| = |B|$.

Tags: combinatorics

A graph is $k$-regular if every vertex has degree $k$. Show that if a bipartite graph $G = (V, E)$ with bipartition $V = A \cup B$ is k-regular, then $|A| = |B|$.

I dont understand it. Please explain and show the proof so I can understand.

Comment: undirected graph, I assume?

Comment: Yes, undirected graph

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint.  Say $|A| = a$, $|B| = b$.  How many edges are there coming out of $A$? How many edges are there coming into $B$?

Comment: One edge coming out of A and one edge coming into B?

Comment: Drawing a picture might help